# Understanding functions and requirement pascal & C#

Tags: c#, arrays, pascal

I am new to C# and have some limited experience in pascal. I am really trying to understand the difference of the functions and requirements. so with pascal the  length of the array is part of the arraytype.

so for example

```
type arrayTest = array[ 1 . . 20 ] of integer
```

so this would mean that any value with the type "arrayTest" would be an array of length 20 whose entries are int.

So for my question to C# what would be an example of a C# function that with those requirement cannot be written in Pascal, but could still be work in C#?

Comment: You ask: *...that with those requirement cannot be written in Pascal, but could still be work in C#?*. Why do you ask? Why do you think there would be some array type that could be written in C# but not in Pascal?

Comment: If you mean "what can you do in C# that isn't possible in Pascal" that would be very broad and depend on the exact versions of both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this in C# like this. `int[] array = new int[5];`. It says that’s it is integer array with the length 5. With all the 5 items initialised to 0 by default.

You can refer this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/single-dimensional-arrays#array-initialization) for more details.

Comment: sorry i wrote can instead of cannot, i rephrased my question.

Comment: As asker gave a Pascal example of array with indexes 1..20, you may want to point out that your example is indexed from 0 to 4